# Google chart - eventhandler on zoom

Tags: javascript, events, google-visualization, listener, zooming

I need to get the selected datetime range when a user is zooming into a chart.

I have enabled the "dragToZoom" Action via

```
Actions = new[] { "dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset" }.
```

All is working as expected, but I'm not able to get into the event. What I wonna do is to switch to an other data resolution when the zoom has changed. I have to handle about 100.000 rows over a range of 3 month. I'm using a server side function which adjusts the visible data accuracy depending on the number of returning values + requested date range.

Any hint would be welcome,
thanks a lot,
Maks

Comment: I'm also looking for an `onZoom` event. I'll let you know if I come up with something